# Windows Server 2012R2 DHCP Scope Preference

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, dhcpv6

I have three scopes setup in DHCP.
Subnets 0, 1, and 2; setup with the preference of 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Yet when I tell a client to renew its address it gets an address from subnet 1.

What is the preference for if it does not affect which scope the client gets put in?

The DHCP server is setup on all three subnets, and the router is sending advertisements on all three subnets. We are using stateful addressing.

Comment: What do you mean by subnets?

Comment: As in 2001:0DB8:4545:0::,2001:0DB8:4545:1::,2001:0DB8:4545:2::.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address
https://www.arin.net/knowledge/ipv6_info_center.html

The fourth 'field' (I don't know the proper name), is the subnet.

Comment: Ok. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Clients get their number from subnet 0 (or first preference), then if for some reason that subnet runs out of numbers dhcp assigns out of subnet 1, etc. Is this not the way that the preference assignment is to be used?

Comment: Renew it a few more times, and see what exactly happens, and post it.

Comment: I released then renewed 5 times and got 5 unique addresses on subnet 1 that is setup with a preference of 2.

Comment: Has it ever got preference 1?

Comment: I have swapped the preferences around playing with it yes. What are your proposing? I have restarted the DHCP service when I change the preference values.

Comment: When I swap the binding it swaps what subnet gets assigned. Preference will most likely not be an issue if I can bind the server to all three addresses assigned to it.

http://serverfault.com/questions/693897/more-than-one-static-address-binding-for-dhcp

Comment: Honestly I don't know :(