# More Than One Static Address Binding for DHCP?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, dhcpv6

I have my DHCP server setup to be connected to three subnets (ie: 2001:abab:1234:**1**:: or 2001:abab:1234:**2**::) using three unique IP addresses, except in DHCP server binding properties I can only see one of my IPs to bind the DHCP server to.

How can I get Windows to serve all three subnets with DHCP service?

Comment: Are these three unique network adapters?

Comment: No, it is a single adapter which is assigned three IP addresses (a:b:c:0::1, a:b:c:1::1, and a:b:c:3::1).

Comment: DHCP server bindings are per connection (interface), not per ip address. I'm fairly certain that it will only bind to the first configured ip address per connection (interface).

Comment: So Windows DHCP can only have a single subnet per interface?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK the DHCP server will bind only to the first configured ip address per connection (interface).